# How do I force reset on Samsung Galaxy Tab A SM-T510 tablet w/o home button if password was forgotten?

Tags: factory-reset

I cannot turn it off because it asks for the password.  I can not restart it without password.  I cannot do anything without the password.  The combinations I have found on the internet have not worked either.  Not sure what else to do.  There is no home button, or menu button available in this funky on mode.  Can't get to settings.  A google account had not yet been linked to the tablet as it had just been purchased, had not finished the set up when I was interrupted by my kid who it was bought for.  So when I was interrupted I had not yet written down the password to be put in my lockbox.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3927366

Answer (score 1):

Power Button + Vol Down until the screen goes black
Then hold Power Button + Vol Up